# Dynamodb nodejs client throws an exception and the exception is an empty object

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I get this exception several times in the logs. I am using nodejs and the dynamodb client throws an exception when inserting an object. I have wrapped the code in try catch block and log the exception. But the exception is just an empty object. Any insights would be awesome.

```
try {
  // documentClient is the instantiated dynamo client
  await documentClient.put(params).promise();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```